# schema.org microdata. Is there a way to specify that a property has been intentionally excluded?

Tags: schema.org

I'm trying to configure schema.org microdata in a job listing website.

My microdata passes validation without errors, however there is a warning, which I ideally would like to resolve.

For our application, Salary isn't relevant. It will never be included in the job listings, and it doesn't exist in our data models. However Google flags the following warning...

> The baseSalary field is recommended. Please provide a value if
>   available.

Is there some way to indicate in the microdata, that a property has been intentionally excluded, so that it can pass validation cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a warning, not a requirement. If you want to make pass validation, you can use a dummy amount like £0.